# Как соедeнить два DataFrame в pandas

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть код

```
import pandas
d = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]})
f = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [2], 'c': [1], 'b': [3],})
c = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [2], 'g': [4], 'b': [3], })
r = pandas.concat([d, f, c])
print(r)
```

В итоге я получаю

```
a b c g
1 2 
2 3 1 
      4
```

ключ "c", не переходил в конец, а оставался в середине.
Вот так:

```
a c g b
1     2
2 1   3
    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Перенумеровать колонки также можно с помощью метода `reindex()`

```
import pandas
d = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]})
f = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [2], 'c': [1], 'b': [3],})
c = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [2], 'g': [4], 'b': [3], })
r = pandas.concat([d, f, c]).reindex(columns=['a', 'c', 'g', 'b'])
print(r)
```

Вывод

```
   a    c    g  b
0  1  NaN  NaN  2
0  2  1.0  NaN  3
0  2  NaN  4.0  3
```

Описание `reindex()` см. на https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html

Comment: А если я хочу сделать так: ```import pandas
d = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]})
f = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [2], 'c': [1], 'b': [3],})
c = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [2], 'g': [4], 'b': [3], })
r = pandas.concat([f, c, d])
print(r)```

Comment: Обновил ответ. Можно сделать переиндексацию столбцов через метод `reindex()`

Answer (score 1):

Так это же вопрос отображения. Вы всегда можете выбрать колонки в нужном порядке (и присвоить датафрейм с таким порядком отображения обратно в ваш датафрейм, если хотите):

```
r = r[['a','c','g','b']]
print(r)
```

Вывод:

```
   a    c    g  b
0  1  NaN  NaN  2
0  2  1.0  NaN  3
0  2  NaN  4.0  3
```

Comment: А если захочу в excel записать?

Comment: Через `r.to_excel`